# Java Xtext/EMF Resource Factory Impl NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, emf

**UPDATE**: I solved it by removing and reimporting my project as well the dependencies

I recently updated eclipse from **neon3** modeling edition to **oxygen2** modeling edition. While my code worked perfectly with **neon3**, in **oxygen2** after importing my workspace and updating the classpath and the dependencies, while on execution of the program, `NoClassDefFoundError` occurs on `org/eclipse/emf/ecore/xmi/impl/EcoreResourceFactoryImpl`.

Here i provide the code that produces the error stack as well a part of the stack

```
/*
 * generated by Xtext 2.10.0
 */
public class MyAppDslStandaloneSetupGenerated implements ISetup {

    @Override
    public Injector createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration() {
        // register default ePackages
        if (!Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().containsKey("ecore"))
            Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(
                "ecore", new EcoreResourceFactoryImpl());
        if (!Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().containsKey("xmi"))
            Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(
                "xmi", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());

        Injector injector = createInjector();
        register(injector);
        return injector;
    }


...

}
```

StackTrace:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/xmi/impl/EcoreResourceFactoryImpl
        at com.xtext.myapp.MyAppDslStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(MyAppDslStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:27)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.EcoreResourceFactoryImpl
```

Plugin Dependencies:

[image: Plugin Dependencies]

I have done some research on the net but I couldn't figure out whats wrong. The

Comment: did you check your classpath? the plugin missing seems to be `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi`

Comment: yes I have checked it. It exists in the classpath. The same project at eclipse neon3 works ok.

Comment: How do you execute

Comment: i press the run as java application

Comment: Can you list the plugin dependencies

Comment: Added dependencies on the post

Comment: Have no idea sry

Comment: Did you try this with fresh HelloWorld project

Comment: this stacktrace indicates that this plugin is missing?

Comment: yes. does open type dialog find it ? (EcoreResourceFactoryImpl)

Comment: yes it opens. I wonder why it runs ok on neon...

Comment: without a reproducible example i have no idea. are you sure there is only one plugin involved on your side

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Is the plugin dependencies you showed at the place where it fails

Comment: The dependencies are at the place that fails. But the createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration() is called from  the main project. I have also tried to include xmi plugin at the main project which has the Swing classes but the same error occurs

Comment: As I said I’d need a reproducible sample

Comment: i readded the dependencies and now its working. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi` is added/avaiable on the dependencies of the plugin